# The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a query and i want to order by CreatationDateTime form requestFolders
But I get this error.

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

my query is :

```
with requests as    (
select IRF.Id as Id,
    P.Id as ProcessId,
    N'Investment' as [ServiceType],
    IRF.FolderNumber as FolderNumber,
    P.[Name] as [TypeTitle],
    S.CustomerDisplayInfo_CustomerTitle as [CurrentStatus],
    S.CustomerDisplayInfo_CustomerOrder as [CurrentStatusOrder],
    RH.OccuredDateTime as [CurrentStatusDate],
    IRF.CreationDateTime as [RequestDate],
    IRF.RequestedAmount as [Amount],
    (case when A.Id is not Null and s.sidetype='CustomerSide' then 1 else 0 end)  as [HasAction],
    rank() over ( partition by IRF.Id order by rh.OccuredDateTime desc) as rnk
from
    [Investment].[dbo].[InvestmentRequestFolders] as IRF inner join
    [Investment].[dbo].[RequestHistories] as RH on IRF.Id = RH.ObjectId inner join
    [Investment].[dbo].[Processes] as P on P.Id = RH.ProcessId inner join
    [Investment].[dbo].[Step] as S on S.Id = RH.ToStep left join
    [Investment].[dbo].[Actions] as A on A.StepId = RH.ToStep

where IRF.Applicant_ApplicantId = '89669CD7-9914-4B3D-AFEA-61E3021EEC30'

-- the error is here
order by IRF.CreationDateTime

) SELECT t.Id,
    max(t.ProcessId) as [ProcessId],
    t.[ServiceType] as [ServiceType],
    isnull(max(t.TypeTitle), '-') as [TypeTitle],
    isnull(max(t.FolderNumber), '-') as [RequestNumber],
    isnull(max(t.CurrentStatus), '-') as [CurrentStatus],
    isnull(max(t.CurrentStatusOrder), '-') as [CurrentStatusOrder],
    max(t.CurrentStatusDate)as [CurrentStatusDate],
    max(t.RequestDate) as [RequestDate],
    max(t.HasAction) as [HasAction],
    isnull(max(t.Amount), 0) as [Amount]
FROM requests as t

where t.rnk = 1

GROUP BY t.Id
```

The error is on Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 24

Please help me.

Comment: The error is *literally* telling you the problem; what about it don't you understand here and we can try to elaborate.

Comment: You could try to put an ORDER BY on your main query to order the rows of your query's end result. If that's not what you want or need, you should explain that in more detail.

Comment: A CTE is logically a table - really just syntactic sugar for a derived table. Sort your resultset in the final SELECT statement, not in the CTE. Related - you (or more likely someone else) will regret the use of 3 part names. Let the connection determine the database to be used. Don't add to the issues someone else must fix when using your code with a different database.

Comment: **The ORDER BY clause** this is part of an SQL statement with `order by` in it **is invalid** means not valid **in views** something declared with `create view`, **inline functions** a table function with a single `return`, **derived tables** declared by using `()` around the `select`, **subqueries** similar except they are within other expressions, **and common table expressions,** declared by `with` **unless `TOP`, `OFFSET` or `FOR XML` is also specified** one of these must be part of the same `select`. If you could tell us what you are trying to do with the `order by` maybe we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In almost all cases, you can simply drop the CTE's `ORDER BY` clause. Even if it were permitted syntactically (it is in other RDBMS), it has no effect on your query's result the way you wrote it.

Now, if for some reason, you absolutely have to keep it there, you can add a `TOP` clause, e.g. one without any effect such as `TOP 100 PERCENT`, i.e.:

```sql
with requests as    (
  select top 100 percent
    IRF.Id as Id,
    ...
```

A full, simplified example:

```sql
-- Doesn't work
with t (a) as (
  select a
  from (values (1),(3),(2)) t (a)
  order by a
)
select a from t order by a

-- Works
with t (a) as (
  select top 100 percent a
  from (values (1),(3),(2)) t (a)
  order by a
)
select a from t order by a
```

Comment: `top 100 percent` *also* has no effect although it is syntactically valid, not sure if that is what you meant but isn't clear

Comment: @Charlieface: Yes, it's a hack to make the original query work without changing semantics.